# Need to know the commands to Start and Stop Microfocus Server

Tags: aix

I have microfocus server installed on AIX. What I figured out is, all the servers are there at :

```
cd /var/mfcobol/es
# ls -l
total 40

drwxr-xr-x    2 root     system          256 Aug 13 09:53 ABCD
drwxr-xr-x    2 mfuser   system         4096 May 13 13:17 AISDEV
drwxr-xr-x    2 mfuser   system          256 Apr 23 16:40 AISPRD
drwxr-xr-x    2 mfuser   system         4096 Aug 06 19:07 AIXDEV
drwxr-xr-x    2 mfuser   system         4096 Aug 06 13:35 AIXPRD
drwxr-xr-x    2 mfuser   system         4096 Aug 06 13:28 AIXUAS
drwxr-xr-x    2 mfuser   system          256 Apr 29 19:59 ESDEMO
```

1. As per the above results these are mounted on `/var` and Filesystem is `/dev/hd9var`. 
   I would like to know the actions to be executed in case that we need (or we receive a request) to stop and start AIXDEV and AIXUAS partitions on AIX machine. (Also let me know whether my finding about the Microfocus server installation at `/var/mfcobol/es` is correct or not).
2. Is there any other way to find out where exactly my Microfocus server is installed on my AIX machine?
3. What are the commnads to start and Stop the Microfocus Server. For example if i need to start/stop only Dev derver (AIXDEV), what is the command for that?

Answer (score 1):

A) How to **start** Microfocus Server

To start Enterprise Server Administration, enter the following commands:

```
su root
cd $COBDIR/bin
mfds &
exit
```

Then open a Web browser and specify http://host:86, where host is the machine on which Enterprise Server for UNIX is installed.

Another way to start the Microfocus Server is by using the command:

```
casstart -rAIXDEV (AIXDEV is the name of the server you want to start)
```

Below is the example for the same:

```
# /opt/microfocus/cobol/bin/casstart -rAIXDEV

CASSI1872S Requested enterprise server instance already started 11:38:50
```

B) How to **stop** Microfocus Server

There are 2 ways to stop the Microfocus server, below is the description for the same.

1. On Unix  platforms, you can stop it on the left hand side panel of the Enterprise Server Administration page (Actions / Shutdown)
2. Or from the commandline:

   ```
   mfds [-p port-number] –s 2 [username password]
   ```

(shutdown the Directory Server and any associated enterprise servers)

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere